# Get values of subarrary wordpress get_options

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I have a repeatable colorpicker field within a wordpress admin plugin. These values get saved to the database.

I can get the debug to show me the array from these fields fine. See Below.

```
echo '<pre>APF_AdvancedSections[repeatable_tabbed_section][1][my_color]: ' . AdminPageFramework::getOption( 'APF_AdvancedSections', array( 'repeatable_tabbed_section', '0', 'color' ), 'default color value' ) . '</pre>';
```

Returns

```
Array
(
    [repeatable_tabbed_section] => Array
        (
            [my_color] => Array
                (
                    [0] => #dd3333
                    [1] => #dd9933
                    [2] => #1e73be
                    [3] => #8224e3
                )

        )

)
```

I now would like to display and use just the hex codes within the my_color array.
I have tried using the below code to display these but i only get `repeatable_tabbed_section` displayed on the page

```
$my_options = get_option( 'APF_AdvancedSections' );
     foreach($my_options as $keyapf=>$value):
    echo "<tr>
        <td>" . $keyapf . "</td>
    </tr>";
    endforeach;
```

How am I able to loop the results of my_color?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that the structure of the return is as such, you can loop over the `my_color` index.

```
foreach($my_options['repeatable_tabbed_section']['my_color'] as $idx => $color){
    echo '<tr> ', $color ,' </tr>';
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! will be saving that snippet! New to arrays.